# Rails has_one one-way association that is not obligatory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm, model, associations

I have such models

```
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :office
end

class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :agency
end
```

The problem is I have no idea how to create such a relation, that is not obligatory (some agencies can have office, others - can be just online-agencies without office). With current approach when adding any agency I have to build office every time, even if there is no data, like this, just to store empty related record:

```
agency = Agency.create!(attributes)
agency.build_office
agency.save!
```

What is the right way to do that?

**Update**

Actually, this problem arises when I use forms like this:

```
form_for @agency.....
...
  fields_for @agency.office ...
```

If there is no office record in the database, I get some error (related with building names from class names or something like that).

Or should I simply build @office object in controller and pass it directly to view instead of simply passing @agency and using non-existent @agency.office?

**Update**

Decided to split form into separate independent parts with separate controllers, cause it is really uncomfortable to keep everything on one page.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Why do you have to make the office?

Comment: If there is no office already, I can not use inside `form_for @agency ...` things like `fields_for @agency.office ...` if there is no office already in the database. Maybe, this is incorrect approach (I'm new to Rails). Maybe, I do not need that, but how should I use form than?

Comment: Ok, yes you will need to build the office if you're using `nested_attributes_for` but you could always create the office after with an `OfficesController` so that the user would only need to create one if it's necessary

Comment: Thanks, that is the thing I was thinking about. Will try and see :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing was to refuse from using `nested_attributes_for` and create two different objects. And later create or update them in trasaction if needed. That will remove all complexity and problems related to building unnecessary things before they are really needed.